# how to add image to a user in active directory?

Tags: sharepoint, active-directory

I have a custom list in which there is one column as employee which has datatype as 'person or group' in sharepoint 2010. now i want the picture of users in peaplepicker box of employee. How can i do this.

Also i want to know how to add image to a user in active directory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thier are two aspects of your problem first to add images to profile for that you would have to update users profile in sharepoint or active directory with his pictures.
second part where you want to show image of a person with people picker. for this you would have to create a custom people picker follow the code provided in article below to create custom people picker field type 
1. this post will provide help how to customize people picker 
http://panvega.wordpress.com/2008/02/22/custom-sharepoint-people-picker/
2. this post will provide help to create new field type 
http://www.alectang.com/blog/archive/2009/11/23/creating-custom-field-type-in-sharepoint-list-50.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Does sharepoint use the thumbnailphoto/jpegPhoto attribute?

If it does you can use powershell to update the image file. ([TechNet Forums](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en/ITCG/thread/403cda19-7a63-4d95-a273-8f7885e836cd))

```
[byte[]]$jpg = Get-Content c:\photo.jpg -encoding byte
$user = [adsi]"LDAP://cn=user1,cn=users,dc=domain,dc=loc"
$user.Properties["jpegPhoto"].Clear()
$null = $user.Properties["jpegPhoto"].Add($jpg)
$user.CommitChanges()
```